# how come image wont load on website as href?

Tags: html, css, jpeg, href

im really new to this but heres my problem.  I need to upload a pic onto my website (im using aptana studios 3). So i save my image as jpeg and use the code:
  
now it acknowledges that I am uploading the picture but it won't load.  Do i have to convert the image or save it a certain way?

Comment: no clue, how about post the code for the image you are using, include html css etc.

Comment: how do i get the picture into that form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh buddy, make sure to post the code you're having issues with. In any case, it doesn't really matter what file extension you use (though `.png` may be the best for web). I'm assuming this is hard-coded `HTML`, if that is the case, I would use a simple `<img />` element to display a picture. Make sure the image is saved in a nearby directory.

```
<div>
    <div class="item"><img src="./example.png"/></div>
</div>
```

In the example above, `example.png` is located in the same folder as my `index.html` file. We use the attribute `src`, not `href`. An `href` attribute dictates what page is to be loaded when an element, e.g. an `<a>` element, is clicked on. If you have a `CSS` stylesheet, it might be preferable to load the image as a `background-image` to a `<div>` element, so that it would be easier to manipulate image properties like height and width. An example of that would be:

```
<div>
   <div class="item"/></div>
</div>
```

..and the `CSS`:

```
.item {
    background-image: url("boxes.png");
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Here, I set the image's height and width, and tell my styles that I want the whole image to be show with `background-size: contain;`.

I hope this helps.